# combine python function with for loops in bash terminal

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

I aimed to open multiple files (one by one, using for loop in bash terminal) and modify it using PLINK (a programme) and later on, python function. Following are the codes:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  plink --cow --noweb --lfile $i --extract extract1.snp --recode --out 1$i
  python -c 'import file_convert;file_convert.convert_tree_mix("1$i.map","tmp$i")'
done
```

But, as expected, python could not read and could not open "11.map", it did not replace "$i" with 1. How can i modify the code so that python function, in combination with for loop, open different file each time based on the value of "i"

Comment: try `python -c "import file_convert;file_convert.convert_tree_mix(\"1$i.map\",\"tmp$i\")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the whole python code inside double quotes, so that the `$1` inside the python code will expand. `$1` in shell refers to the first parameter.

```
python -c "import file_convert;file_convert.convert_tree_mix(\"1$i.map\",\"tmp$i\")"
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried calling python like that:

```
python -c 'import sys; import file_convert;file_convert.convert_tree_mix(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])' "1$i.map" "tmp$i";
```

?

Comment: In general, this is better than trying to use shell interpolation to build a dynamic string for Python to execute.